# When comparing List elements to a user entered string only the last entered list element seems to be compared

Tags: c#, winforms, list, string-comparison

My program has a list of people and a list of events, and it is the job of the program to sell tickets to these events, to the people entered into the list.

I'm a the stage where I need to program in the function that allows the user to select the show/event they would like to buy tickets to. I have decided to do this by displaying the available events in a RichTextBox and asking the user to write the name of the event that they would like to buy tickets to. If this event is present then the program should advance to the customer details form; if not then it should reset the input TextBox and display an error message to the user - simple enough.

However, for some reason when I try to search the list and compare the String "chosenArtist" to the `event.getArtist()` method it returns as not found for items that are actually present in the list. The only item it actually seems to return is the last entered list item.

For example:

1. Clown
2. Singer
3. Dancer

The compare function would tell me that Clown and Singer do not exist, but that Dancer does.

I think its something to do with either the code I have inside my foreach loop, or the actual code for the Events class, but I just don't know.

Code for AddCustomer form
(Comparison is done inside `btnFind_click`)

```
public partial class AddCustomer : Form
{
    //arrayList
    List<Person> personList = new List<Person>();
    List<Events> eventsList = new List<Events>();

    //class
    Person p = new Person();
    Events ev = new Events();

    //variables 
    String chosenArtist;

    //constructors
    public AddCustomer()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public AddCustomer(List<Events> eventsList, List<Person> personList)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.personList = personList;
        this.eventsList = eventsList;
    }

    private void btnHome_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        formHome home = new formHome();
        this.Hide();
        home.Show();
    }

    private void AddCustomer_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //sets error label text to blank
        lblCustomerError.Text = "";

        //sets display for rich text box
        rtbAddCust.Text = "Events\n";

        foreach (Events ev in eventsList)
        {
            rtbAddCust.AppendText("Artist name: " + ev.getArtist() + "\n" +
                             "Event venue: " + ev.getVenue() + "\n" +
                             "Event date: " + ev.getDate() + "\n" +
                             "Capacity: " + ev.getCapacity() + "\n" +
                             "Price: £" + ev.getPrice() + "\n" +
                             "Remaining tickets: " + ev.getRemaining() + "\n\n");
        }

        //Ensures curser always starts at top of text box
        rtbAddCust.SelectionStart = 0;
        rtbAddCust.ScrollToCaret();
    }

    private void btnFind_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        chosenArtist = txtFindArtist.Text;

        foreach(Events ev in eventsList)
        {
            //compares chosen artist to list items to determine if present
            if (ev.getArtist().ToLower().Equals(chosenArtist.ToLower()))
            {
                lblCustomerError.Text = "Artist found";

                //do something
            }
            else
            {
                lblCustomerError.Text = "artist not found";
                txtFindArtist.Clear();
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

Code for Events Class

```
public class Events
{
   private String artist;
   private String venue;
   private String date;
   private String capacity;
   private String remaining;
   private String price;

    public Events() { }

    public Events(String artist, String venue, String date, String capacity, String remaining, String price ) 
    {
        this.artist = artist;
        this.venue = venue;
        this.date = date;
        this.capacity = capacity;
        this.remaining = remaining;
        this.price = price;
    }

    //setters

    public void setArtist(String artist) { this.artist = artist; }

    public void setVenue(String venue) { this.venue = venue; }

    public void setDate(String date) { this.date = date; }

    public void setCapacity(String capacity) { this.capacity = capacity; }

    public void setRemaining(String remaining) { this.remaining = remaining; }

    public void setPrice(String price) { this.price = price; }

    //getters

    public String getArtist() { return artist; }

    public String getVenue() { return venue; }

    public String getDate() { return date; }

    public String getCapacity() { return capacity; }

    public String getRemaining() { return remaining; }

    public String getPrice() { return price; }

    //toString
    public override String ToString() { return artist + " " + venue + " " + date + " " + capacity + " " + remaining + " " + price; }
```

It might also be important to note that if for example inside the `foreach` loop I changed the text inside my RichTextBox to just print out the names of artist this works fine. It only seems to be when I try to compare these names to something that I have a problem.

Comment: Side note: your sample lookls like Java code (or slightly adopted from Java). Please use properties in C# (likely auto-implemented properties would work for your case like `public string Capacity {get;set;}`).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov the issue was in `btnFind` click handler. He was not breaking from loop after successful match and next comparison resulted in "not found"

Comment: @TheVillageIdiot - get it... Name of `AddCustomer` is completely unrelated to waht code does  - so looked like it could be an issue...

Comment: Why would you ask the user to type in the name of an event when you can just give them some mechanism to select it? It seems like this will annoy the users more than anything. If you are making a search box that pulls up a list of matching or similar items from which the user can make a selection, then that would be okay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following event handler is causing issue. Check `if`, suppose I enter 'Singer' in textbox and click Find. It will compare it with first item **Clown** which results in mismatch, then it compares it with **Singer** which is a match. But you continue to compare it with next item **Dancer** which is again a mismatch. You need to `break` from loop once match is found:

```
private void btnFind_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    chosenArtist = txtFindArtist.Text;

    foreach(Events ev in eventsList)
    {
        //compares chosen artist to list items to determine if present
        if (ev.getArtist().ToLower().Equals(chosenArtist.ToLower()))
        {
            lblCustomerError.Text = "Artist found";

            //do something

            break;//BREAK FROM LOOP
        }
        else
        {
            lblCustomerError.Text = "artist not found";
            txtFindArtist.Clear();
        }
    } 
}
```

A slight cleaner implementation may go like this:

```
private void btnFind_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    chosenArtist = txtFindArtist.Text.ToUpperInvariant;
    var found=false;

    foreach(Events ev in eventsList)
    {
        if (ev.getArtist().ToUpperInvariant().Equals(chosenArtist))
        {
            found=true;
            break;//BREAK FROM LOOP
        }
    } 

    if(found){
        lblCustomerError.Text = "Artist found";
        //Do booking stuff
    }
    else
    {
        lblCustomerError.Text = "Artist not found";
        txtFindArtist.Clear();
    }
}
```

EDIT:- As noted by @AlexiLevenkov you can take advantage of **auto properties** in C#. You `Event` class will look like this if coded by some C# dev.

public class Events
{
   public String Artist {get;set;}
   public String Venue {get;set;}
   public String Date {get;set;}
   public String Capacity {get;set;}
   public String Remaining {get;set;}
   public String Price {get;set;}

```
public Events() { }

public Events(String artist, String venue, String date, String capacity,
                                               String remaining, String price ) 
{
    Artist = artist;
    Venue = venue;
    Date = date;
    Capacity = capacity;
    Remaining = remaining;
    Price = price;
}

public override String ToString()
{ 
    return artist + " " + venue + " " + date + " " + capacity + " " + 
               remaining + " " + price; 
}
```

}

Also do give a thought to take proper data types for `Date`, `Price`, `Capacity` etc.

Comment: +1. Using `Enumerable.FirstOrDefault` or `Enumerable.Any` would make code cleaner and harder to make this error.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Sure but as he is new one in C# it will take some time.

Comment: @TheVillageIdiot Thanks for the help and the answer, I feel a bit silly realizing how simple a fix it was!  I had been playing around with writing to text files and such so had everything set to Strings and totally forgot to change them back to the correct formats.  All is fixed now.  I learned set and get while studying java and never even thought about changing it but I have since researched doing it in c#.  Thanks again!